# Regarding installation of windows 8 alongside Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, windows-8

I have purchased a laptop that came with an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS comes as an pre-installed OS. I want to install Windows 8 alongside with Ubuntu 12.04.

How can i do that?

Can i download `gparted` and create extra NTFS partitions and install Windows 8??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Ubuntu now then Installing Windows over it will erase the Ubuntu Grub and you will not be able to open the Ubuntu. So the kind suggestion would be: First of all format all the partition and separate the partition for windows and Ubuntu and then install Window and then install Ubuntu.